# kendo grid after resize, reorder, column hide or column show, grid dataSource will be null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid and my bebavior is below:

- Reorder column using mouse drag&drop
- Resize column using mouse drag&drop
- Hide column by columnMenu
- Show column by columnMenu

After those event, `grid.dataSource.data() = null`, the whole grid only have the header row, the data rows are disappeared.
I have to add the code to keep the grid looks well:

```
columnReorder: function(e) {
    $timeout(function () {$scope.grid.dataSource.data(e.sender.dataSource.data());});
},
columnResize: function(e) {
    $timeout(function () {$scope.grid.dataSource.data(e.sender.dataSource.data());});
},
columnHide: function(e) {
    $timeout(function () {$scope.grid.dataSource.data(e.sender.dataSource.data());});
},
columnShow: function(e) {
    $timeout(function () {$scope.grid.dataSource.data(e.sender.dataSource.data());});
}
```

But I have no idea about why the grid data lost when I resize/reorder/hide/show the column.

Please help me out.

Comment: try empty array? grid.dataSource.data([])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause: When I use kendo-grid I set an attribute:`k-rebind="gridOption"`

see more details:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/angular-k-rebind-grid-column-resize-causes-refresh